# Detect at runtime which GCC -march flag to use

Tags: c, gcc, cpu-architecture

I’m trying to programmatically detect at runtime what would be the best GCC `-march` flag for a given CPU. The program I’m developing will download optimized binaries depending on the user's CPU architecture. So I must detect which architecture it is in this list:

- `core2`
- `nehalem`
- `westmere`
- `sandybridge`
- `ivybridge`
- `haswell`
- `broadwell`
- `generic` (is all above failed).

Like this command: `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep -- '-march=' | cut -f3`, without invoking GCC of course (I can’t embed it). I found the function `__builtin_cpu_is` of GCC, but it does not support all architectures.

I’m looking for a portable way of doing so, at least for GNU/Linux, Windows and OSX. I’m only planning to use GCC as compiler.

Comment: For Linux you might try `lscpu` shell command, which has an 'Architecture' field.

Comment: You can use [function multi versioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning) to provide several function versions optimized for specific architectures. You can probably use the same mechanism to detect which optimized binary should be downloaded.

Comment: See volume 1 chapter 17 of the [Intel processor programmer's guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html) for an introduction to the `CPUID` instruction.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to produce a different binary for each architecture, then at run-time pick which binary to run.

Comment: @Mysticial - I believe that's how Intel compilers do it, albeit by jumping to copies of functions within the same binary rather than creating multiple distinct binaries.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `lscpu` does not give me enough informations, the architecture is reported as `x86_64`.

Comment: @Banthar Your solution seemed the best one for this question, unfortunately, it does not support the latest architectures (e.g. `ivybridge`, `haswell`, ...).